# After I split a string, how would I modify each word independently? - Java

Tags: java, arrays, split, append, stringbuilder

For example, if I have a string called '`S`', split it using `.split` and store all the words in `String[] arr = s.split(" ")`, how would I modify each word? Let's say I want to remove the first letter and add into the end, then insert some more characters. I know I'll be using `StringBuilder` class and `deleteCharAt,` `append()`, etc..

Ex. Hello World ----> elloHto orldWto

Comment: its the same way as you do without the `split` method

Answer (score 0):

```
    String input = "Hello World";
    String[] words = input.split(" ");
    for(String s: words){
        System.out.println(s); //do whatever you want
    }
```